# Is it possible to detect the OS core is DOS or NT in Python?

Tags: python, module, io, operating-system

The following code:

```py
import os
print(os.name)
```

However, when I use Windows Me(DOS core) or Windows NT 4.0 Workstation SP6(NT core), the output is the same: `nt` .
So is it possible to detect the OS core is DOS or NT in Python? If it is, how?

Comment: What version of Python are you using that runs on either of these extremely old operating systems? The last time either OS was supported, Python 2.6 and Python 3.0 were still years away from release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'platform' module to check:

```
In [244]: import platform

In [247]: platform.version()
Out[247]: '6.1.7601'

In [248]: platform.system()
Out[248]: 'Windows'

In [249]: platform.release()
Out[249]: '7'

In [250]: platform.win32_ver()
Out[250]: ('7', '6.1.7601', 'SP1', 'Multiprocessor Free')

In [268]: platform.platform()
Out[268]: 'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Technical Preview builds are currently identified as Windows NT 6.4 so this *maybe* a reason of you getting output to be **NT** use platform library instead.